Programmatically open SwiftUI Picker when focused and enter key is pressed
I have a simple SwiftUI Picker. I am trying to enable keyboard navigation on iPad.
I have it set up like this
Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor) {
   Text("Chocolate").tag(Flavor.chocolate)
   Text("Vanilla").tag(Flavor.vanilla)
}
.focusable()

And while this allows me to tab on iPad to the picker. It does not allow me to interact with the picker with the keyboard using the enter key. How might I enable this?
I essentially need to programmatically open the picker when the enter key is pressed. While I can detect when the enter key is pressed I am not sure how I could manually open it.
Ideally if I press enter I would be able to see this


Picker already has built-in keyboard navigation. You don't need .focusable(). Just turn the setting on in the Settings app.
